# Python - Check if function returns value and capture it if so

Tags: python, if-statement

At first, this question may seem rather stupid.  But for some reason, I cannot figure it out for the life of me. I have some function, lets call it `foo`.  `foo` will either return `False` or a unique string / number depending on what parameters are passed to it.  I want to check if `foo` returns some value other then `False`, and if so process it.  If it doesn't, I want to go on and do the same thing with a different parameter passed to `foo`. It can be done as below:

```
a = foo(1)
b = foo(2)
c = foo(3)
if a:
    print (a)
elif b:
    print (b + 3)
elif c:
    print ("abc" + c)
```

While this method works, it seems "clunky" to me. Is there any better way of doing this?

Comment: "foo will either return False or a unique string / number depending on what parameters are passed to it" When a function can return different types then it is trying to do too many things. The Single Responsibility Principle tells us that a function should do one thing and do it well. I suggest refactoring the existing function into the smaller logical units that it is trying to do all at the same time.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice what about say `def is_a_fish(word): if word in ["sardines", "mackerel", "haddock", "cod"]: return word; return False`? And what about other principles where the docstring shouldn't be longer than the code? I prefer not writing single line functions if at all posssible, as that is reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I see your point, but this is just for example's sake.  In my code, foo is not one function with a bunch of different parameters, but several different functions all given the same parameter.

Comment: @John Why not `return word in [...]`? The caller already has the value passed in as `word`. Why return it?

Comment: @BillyS I appreciate that you created a minimal working example. After your last comment, it seems to me that you may have removed some important features by simplifying too much.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I just realized that myself . . . I have found a working solution for me, but I'll leave this question up in the hopes that it will be useful to someone else.

Answer (score 1):

```
abc = [foo(i) for i in range(1,4)]
for x in abc:
    if x:
        print(x)
        break
```

or even

```
for x in [foo(i) for i in range(1,4)]:
    if x:
        print(x)
        break
```

Is this better than your method is subjective but I personally would prefer a reduced line count and a single collection over disparate variable names. The reason being their extensibility.

As regards the pseudo switch statement you have; no there is no better way although some may prefer to use `dict`s as LUT's. For example:

```
for i, x in enumerate(abc):
    if x:
        print([
            x,
            x+3,
            "abc"+x
        ][i])
        break
```

Comment: I would definitely consider that to be better then my code, thank you.

Comment: I don't think the last version will work. When `x` is a number, `"abc" + x` will get an error. And when it's a string, `x + 3` will get an error.

Comment: You also wouldn't want to use that approach if any of the cases are expensive or have side effects, since you'll calculate all the possible values each time through the loop.

Comment: What you need is a lazy list implementation, so it only calculates the item that's used with the index.